# Property 'map' does not exist on type Object

Tags: typescript

```
type MyStructure = Object[] | Object;

const myStructure: MyStructure = [{ foo: "bar" }];

myStructure.map(); // Property 'map' does not exist on type 'MyStructure'. any
```

The library either delivers an object or an array of this object. How can I type this?

**EDIT**

And how can I access properties like `myStructure["foo"]` in case of `myStructure` will be an object?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because your type means you could have an object, or you could have an array; TypeScript can't determine which members are appropriate.

To test this out, change your type and you'll see the `map` method is now available:

```
type MyStructure = Object[];
```

In your case, the actual solution will be to use a type guard to check that you have an array before attempting to use the `map` method.

```
if (myStructure instanceof Array) {
    myStructure.map((val, idx, []) => { });
}
```

You could also solve your problem using a slightly different definition of `MyStructure`, for example:

```
type MyStructure = any[] | any;
```

Or the narrower:

```
class Test {
    foo: string;
}

type MyStructure = Test[] | Test;
```

Comment: I actually did this with _.isArray(), which of course doesn't work in TypeScript... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sohnee, do you know why this works `type MyStructure = number[] | number;` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Atype%20MyStructure%20%3D%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myStructure%3A%20MyStructure%20%3D%20%5B3%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyStructure.map(n%20%3D%3E%20n*2)%3B%0D%0AmyStructure%20%3D%205%3B)?

Comment: It is only `Object` that will cause you the problem. See the additional two examples of using `any` or the (probably more useful) example using a class that defines whatever you use within the map method (you'll then get better type information inside the function you use to map).

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced this issue of 'Property 'map' does not exist on type Object' while I was trying to use **.map() on non-iterable codes**.. in my case I was using map on *JSON object coming from an API* to convert its keys i.e category into string[] but was constantly getting this error

```
JSON data coming from API -> {
  {
     id:1,
     category:'cat-1'
  },
  {
     id:2,
     category:'cat-2'
  }
```

}

Then I used the JSON methods as

```
objFromAPI = http.get('someUrl');
categoryList: string[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objFromAPI)).map(data => data.category);
```

And hence I was able to iterate on the parsed object as JSON methods converted it to an array

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case I saw map doesn't exist on type.
I had the following code:

```
export interface Categories {
    authors: {
        _key: string
        name: string
    }[]
}
```

and then that was going to another interface

```
....
categories: Categories
```

The solution was to alter the main to contain just a single one as

```
    categories: Category[]
```

with

```
    export interface Category {
        _key: string
        name: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [] to the end of itemProps.

E.g.

```
const {
    data: prescriptions,
    isLoading: loadingPrescriptions,
}: UseQueryResult<PrescriptionProps[], Error> = useQuery<
    PrescriptionProps[],
    Error
>(
    ['patient', 'prescriptions', { patientId: itemId }],
    () =>
        fetchItem({
            type: 'patients',
            id: 'prescriptions',
            query: { queryName: 'patientId', queryValue: itemId },
        }),
    { enabled: !!itemId }
)
```

....

```
{prescriptions?.map( (prescription: PrescriptionProps) => (
```