# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs6

I am developing an Ionic 5 application and I have encountered such an error.

[Property 'map' does not exist on type Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685450/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-object) I tried the solution here, but this time he couldn't find first map.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
//import { map } from 'lodash';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UnitService {
baseUrl='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getUnit(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users`).pipe(
      map(unit => {
        return unit.map((un, index) => {
          un.unIndex = index + 1;
          return un;
        });
      })
    )
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this error

Comment: What is the type of `unit` in the first map?

Comment: `unit` is an object, not an array, so `map` won't work. What do you get when you call `console.log(unit)` before the map?

Comment: Of course unit is array. from baseUrl/users

Comment: Here is array from console [link] https://ibb.co/b6yHNDG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that the `map()` will be receiving an array. Change your code to:

```
map((unit: any[]) => {
 ...
}
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqa4wv) the working stackblitz for the same.